# How could I change database in DSN for Crystal Report using code in VB.Net?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, crystal-reports

I have a problem with changing database for crystal report.

I have design a report using crystal report by using DSN as a data source.

I have two databases such as `aces_database` and `aces_database_2`.

When I log into the `branch1`, the report will take data from `aces_database`.
But when I log into `branch2`, I can make my DSN change database to `aces_database_2`
But the it still take data from `branch1`.

I have the method to change it in `design view`. but I couldn't find the way to change it by code.

How could I configure to change database for crystal report using `vb.net`?

Comment: Instead of changing the DSN using code.. would be better if you use 2 sub reports inside one main report and connect one sub report to `first DSN` and second sub report to `second DSN`. and use supress condition to switch between the reports..

Comment: It's a while since I did this, but as far as I remember one way is to iterate through the Report.Database.Tables collection (or something like that anyway) and set the Connection property. I haven't got it installed at the moment to test it

Comment: @Siva thanks! but i would like the dynamic than this.

Comment: @Ciarán could you give me an example?

Comment: It's been a while I'm afraid. What VS and CR versions are you using? Maybe I can dig something out if I get some time.

Comment: I am using VS08 and CR 9